# How do you list users in Exchange Powershell on an Exchange 2007 environment?

Tags: exchange-2007, powershell, mailbox

I'm trying to verify that I've added a user in our Domain to a shared mailbox. I've used the command in the exchange powershell console:

`add-mailboxpermission 'shared mailbox name here' -User: 'ADlogin' -AccessRights:FullAccess`

I've seen confirmation it was added, but I would like to display the users that are attached to this shared mailbox, How can I see that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to know what permissions has been given on a mailbox:

`Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "shared mailbox name here"`

If you want to know what permissions a specific user has on a mailbox, use:

`Get-MailboxPermission -Identity "Shared mailbox name here" -User "The user with permissions"`

Last but not least, the special "Send on behalf" privilege is set on the mailbox as a multivalue property containing all users who can "Send on behalf" (but not necessarily AS) the mailbox owner. To retrieve a list of all the grantees on a mailbox:

`(Get-Mailbox -Identity "Shared Mailbox Name Here").GrantSendOnBehalfTo`

Don't forget the parentheses :-)

Comment: You're welcome, just added another little nifty snippet, to retrieve users with "Send on behalf" permissions. Enjoy! :-D